# Time to relearn touch typing? (Is this a Emacs / VIM thing?)

Tags: vim, emacs, keyboard

As a kid, I learned to type on a German keyboard<sup>1</sup>?. And even though my mom tried to make me use a "learn how to type with ten fingers" program I never did. My hands have their very own muscle memory about how to type. I found out that I use the index fingers most to reach many characters, while my hands are moving over the keyboard.

Now, here's the kicker (no flame intended!): I use and used emacs a lot and I've never really had an issue with the way I type, or at least it never felt too awkward. From time to time I like to explore VIM (and other editors) to see what has changed and which features are the new and hot features.

I came to the conclusion that, while my fingers /rest close/ to the home row, my hands move a lot and the default keyboard command layout in vim seems to prefere the fingers resting on the home row with little movement of the hands.

I don't consider myself to be a slow touch typist, but could a formal touch type education increase speed and accuracy? Furthermore is this a Emacs / VIM thing?

**UPDATE**: I headed over to http://typeracer.com/ :)

<sup>1</sup>: These days I type on US keyboards while switching between different layouts as needed.

Comment: I can hardly imagine how people can write code all day without knowing how to touch-type. I don't use Emacs, but I can't imagine a situation where your productivity wouldn't skyrocket (perhaps after a short adjustment period) after learning to touch-type.

Comment: May I suggest that you learn touch typing on a Dvorak keyboard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you're a keyboard worker, learn to use a keyboard properly.  No, it's not an Emacs / Vim thing.

Comment: A 'keyboard worker' is someone who spends a lot of working time at a keyboard -- the definition of 'a lot' is vague.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a formal education, but a lot of discipline, concentration, dedication and hard work will make you a touch typist in a few months.

Touch typing will greatly assist you in your life, if you plan to work with computers as your day job.

Force yourself to move your hands as little as possible and use all of your fingers all of your time.

Rest your left fingers on `ASDF`, your right fingers on `HJKL` and start typing. While typing, optimize your reach for every key pressed.

If you plan to be a computer professional, touch typing should be a rite of passage, although it isn't required. But just imagine what would it look like if a master pianist didn't know all keys on piano by heart?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using emacs, makeing Caps_Lock another Ctrl key will ease strain on your little finger, when your hands are "locked" in the home row position.

for ubuntu

```
System->Preferences->Keyboard->
-->Layouts->Layout-Options-Ctrl key position->Make CapsLock an additional Ctrl
```

or for windows

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  Especially if you are going to alt-tab to google/read documentation a lot.
Touch typing as it is good only if you are not going to use mouse and F1-F12 which is never true in modern environment.
If you are going to use them, you'll eventaually switch to some form of mutant of touch-typing. 
(also whoever thouGHT that typing H with riGHT hand is briGHT idea should be shot in THe face. Left hand do it more naturally in huge amount of cases)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say don't worry about it. You're not a secretary or someone who is having to take down dictated speech. It's far more important for a programmer to spend more time thinking about what they're writing rather than how they write it. If speed of typing is your biggest concern over how productive you are I think you're probably productive enough.

Comment: You never need to send email, write any form of documentation or type responses on stackoverflow. Cool, I guess touch typing won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really care? If you do, use the editor that you are more comfortable with. If are you looking for alternative, use M-x viper or learn other emacs extensions that helps you type faster.